# Paypal Recurring Payment Profile- Immediate Access

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring-billing, express-checkout

I have set up a recurring payments profile using the Express Checkout API following [these steps](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/).

In my sandbox merchant & user accounts I see that the payments profile has [been created](https://www.dropbox.com/s/31sewzgwauhw5m9/paypal-recurring-payment-question.png), but no money has been sent and the profile is still in the "pending" state. [See screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/31sewzgwauhw5m9/paypal-recurring-payment-question.png).

It is a subscription to a website, and I want to give the user immediate access. I could grant access to my website immediately when a profile is set up, but then a user could cancel the profile before the payment goes through and gain free temporary access to my site.

Alternatively, I could wait until the profile updates to "active" to grant access, but this [may take many hours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840826/528263) and I want to give the customer access as soon as possible.

How is a digital subscription like this usually handled? Should I be using a different Paypal service? Can I somehow speed up the initial transaction so that the initial payment is processed immediately instead of waiting a few hours? Or is it common practise to "not worry" about the potential of malicious users stealing a few free hours access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to treat the first payment as normal payment and start the subscription from the next period.

So for example for monthly subscription for 10$ user buys normal product for 10$ and you also create a subscription profile that is starting from the next month.

Comment: Using the INITAMT field, or just a normal payment?

Comment: I am not sure how AMT in subscription works. When I wanted instant payments I was using normal payment for first and creating subscription profile with INITAMT of 0 and start date for next month/year/anything.
If amount in subscription will do instant payment and don't set it for pending than it would also be ok, but I didn't test that.

Comment: So it turns out INITAMT doesn't go immediately either (it takes up to 24 hours). Like you suggested, I ended up using a normal payment in addition to the subscription, which starts next month. Full calls with POST params for whole flow here: https://gist.github.com/Crashthatch/9378624